# Read/Write file in android

Tags: android

```
try {
                PrintStream out = new PrintStream(openFileOutput("OutputFile.txt", MODE_PRIVATE));

                str=mIn.getText().toString();
                out.println(str);
                out.close();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

i want to ask if this code create file called(OutputFile)?and if yes where is the path of this file??

Answer (score 1):

> i want to ask if this code create file called(OutputFile)

it creates a file called `OutputFile.txt`

> and if yes where is the path of this file??

you can retrieve its path using [getFileStreamPath](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/content/Context.html#getFileStreamPath(java.lang.String)), which returns the file created with `openFileOutput`

```
  File file = getFileStreamPath("OutputFile.txt");
  String path = null;
  if (file != null) {
       path = file.getPath();
  }
```

Comment: Thanks you so much. please another question? how i can read the content of outputFile??

Comment: use `openFileInput("OutputFile.txt")` to retrieve the `FileInputStream` and read it back